# MySQL Retrieve Rows and Convert them to Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, pivot

I’m using the below query to return the form ids with their attachment ids. Each form can have no attachments, one attachment or two attachments.

```
SELECT form.id       AS 'Form ID', 
       attachment.id AS 'Attachment ID' 
FROM   form, 
       attachment 
WHERE  form.id = attachment.form_id;
```

I'm retrieving the results as follows:

```
+---------+---------------+
| Form ID | Attachment ID |
+---------+---------------+
| 1       | 1             |
| 1       | 2             |
| 2       | 3             |
| 3       | 4             |
| 5       | 5             |
| 5       | 6             |
| 6       | 7             |
+---------+---------------+
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to retrieving the results as follows:

```
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Form ID | Attachment ID - 1 | Attachment ID - 2 |
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 1       | 1                 | 2                 |
| 2       | 3                 | NULL              |
| 3       | 4                 | NULL              |
| 4       | NULL              | NULL              |
| 5       | 5                 | 6                 |
| 6       | 7                 | NULL              |
+---------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563172/please-anyone-help-about-my-case-in-mysql-query?noredirect=1#comment43552043_27563172.This might be help you.

Comment: And never more than 2 attachment? Just do a LEFT JOIN with same table, and check attachment id2 > attachment id1.

Comment: It's never more than 2. How can I check different attachment ids?

Comment: Forget about it, will not work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation and a `left join`:

```
SELECT f.id as `Form ID`,
       MIN(a.id) as `Attachment ID - 1` ,
       (CASE WHEN MIN(a.id) <> MAX(a.id) THEN MAX(a.id) END) as `Attachment ID - 2`
FROM   form f left join
       attachment a
       on f.id = a.form_id
GROUP BY f.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT FormID, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN AttachmentNo % 2 = 1 THEN AttachmentID ELSE 0 END) AS 'Attachment ID - 1', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN AttachmentNo % 2 = 0 THEN AttachmentID ELSE 0 END) AS 'Attachment ID - 2'
FROM (SELECT f.id AS FormID, a.id AS AttachmentID, 
             IF(@formId = @formId:=f.id, @id:=@id+1, @id:=1) AS AttachmentNo
      FROM form f 
      LEFT JOIN attachment ON f.id = a.form_id, (SELECT @formId:= 0, @id:=0) AS A 
      ORDER BY f.id. a.id
     ) AS A
GROUP BY FormID
```